# AttributeError: module 'mypandas' has no attribute 'print_pandas_df'

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following python program `test_pandas.py`.

```
# !/usr/bin/env python3.4
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pprint

import pandas as pd
import mypandas.mypandas

df = pd.read_csv('AllStarFull.csv')

mypandas.print_pandas_df(df,50,8)

# groupby 'player ID'
print('Grouping by Player ID')
gb = df.groupby(['playerID'])
pprint.pprint(list(gb))


# groupby 'yearID'
print('Grouping by Year ID')
gb = df.groupby(['yearID'])
pprint.pprint(list(gb))
```

My folder structure is as follows.

```
--python
  --concepts
    --mypandas
      --mypandas.py
      --__init__.py
    --test_pandas.py
```

When I run the `test_pandas.py` I get the following error.

```
  UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Cubic/playpen/python/concepts/pandas/test_pandas.py", line 11, in <module>
    mypandas.print_pandas_df(df,50,8)
AttributeError: module 'mypandas' has no attribute 'print_pandas_df'
```

`mypandas.py` has the function `print_pandas_df`

```
import pandas as pd
import pprint


def print_pandas_df(df, rows, columns):
    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', rows, 'display.max_columns', columns):
        pprint.pprint(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the full path: directory.filename.methodname:

```
mypandas.mypandas.print_pandas_df(df,50,8)
```

You can also say

```
from mypandas import mypandas
```

and then write your code as is.